# How to visualise fork() in c

Tags: c, fork

So I'm currently learning the fork() system call in C but I just can't seem to wrap my head around what exactly is happening.

This is the code

```
    int id=fork();
    int child_id, status;

    //if id == 0 we are in the child process
    if(id == 0 )
    {
        int pid = getpid()
        printf("this is the child process %d\n", pid);
        int id1=fork()

        if(id1==0)
        {
            //this will return the pid of the grandparent
            int pid2 = getppid();
            printf("this is child no 2 process %d\n", pid2);
        }
        else
        {
            child_id = wait(&status);
            printf("this is parent(%d) of child no 2\n", pid)
        }
    }
    else 
    {

        child_id = wait(&status);
        printf("this is the parent process and we will execute after child %d\n", child_id);
    }
```

And this is how I am visualizing it.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you change your visualization to show an actual forking. I'd show P1 splitting into P1 and C1. And then I'd show C1 splitting into C1 and C1.1. And I'd put arrowheads on the lines to show the direction.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no need to **overcomplicate** the sketch. It is fine the way it is.

Comment: Classic error: `if(id1=0)`, I assume this should be `==`

Comment: @TonyTannous As is, it reflects a moment in time rather than the flow of the program, and there are no actual forks in it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'd add `----` between each level and `T = 0` and `T = 1`. But okay I guess it's opinion based.

Comment: @TonyTannous But then at `T = 1`, you *also* need P1 as well as C1.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz at `T=1` P1 is not forking. But ok it only emphasizes the point of view difference. For me it would be more than clear :)

Comment: The `fork()` function is unusual because (when it succeeds), it returns twice, once in each of two different (but very closely related) processes.  The value in `pid2` after calling `getppid()` is the same as the value in `pid` after calling `getpid()` before the second fork.  It is not the PID of the original process; it is the PID of the first child.  It can be worth using a function to print the PID and PPID at various points.

Answer (score 0):

I am to here explain, So Basically fork() is system call (that provokes the system to user mode to kernal mode). Fork duplicate itself and made a new process same as it is which is called as **Child Procees** and Orginal one called **Parent Process**.

Same means The new one will get Same program counter, same variables ,use same cpu resources and program files that used in parent program. Both Processes share memory address.

fork() takes no arguments but returns intergers which is genrally know as Id's

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    fork();
    fork(); 
    fork();
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

This is sample code to understand what is going in backend.
for first fork():
[1. fork()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBJhm.jpg)

for second fork():
[2. fork()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdEgO.jpg)

for third fork():
[3. fork()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21a79.jpg)

For more Detailed explaination you can refer a youtuber
https://code-vault.net/course/46qpfr4tkz:1603732431896/lesson/16non3fdoh:1603732431950

he taught everything in detail and in a very beautiful way.

I hope this help you guys.